# AWS AppSync - $util.typeOf() retrns 'Map' on variable containing string

Tags: aws-appsync, vtl, aws-appsync-resolver

I'm trying to write an AppSync resolver which updates DynamoDB nested object. In order to create correct UpdateItem expressions, I have to loop through $ctx.args and evaluate if arg is simple type ie. field *updatedAt* that contains a string or a Map.

My $ctx.args:

```
{
  "cognitoDetails": {
    "cognito__username": "jdoe",
    "given_name": "John"
  },
  "updatedAt": "2021-11-24T10:28:56.429Z"
}
```

Im my resolver, when trying to evaluate

```
$util.isMap($ctx.args.cognitoDetails) ## returns true - expected
$util.isMap($ctx.args.updatedAt) ## returns true - unexpected!
```

While trying to find solution to this issue, I discovered also:

```
$util.typeOf($util.time.nowISO8601()) ## returns String which is correct 

#set ( $timestamp = $util.time.nowISO8601() )
$util.typeOf($timestamp) ## returns Map and that is a problem
```

Can someone please point me at right direction and explain what exactly I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: I've just tried this myself with your arguments map and VTL. I can't reproduce the problem and I'm getting what you would expect (true false String String). Are you 100% sure you're not somewhere accidentally sending in a Map?

Comment: Thank you, you are right. I ran this in AWS appsync console and it works fine. My problem however is with appsync-simulator that I'm running locally for development.  This behavior still exist, but anyways I will dig into it.